# How to append a column to a dataframe with values from a specified column index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe in which one of the columns is used to designate which of the other columns has the specific value I'm looking for.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'COL1':['X','Y','Z'],'COL2':['A','B','C'],'X_SORT':['COL1','COL2','COL1']})
```

I'm trying to add a new column called 'X_SORT_VALUE' and assigning the value of the column identified in the X_SORT column.

```
df = df.assign(X_SORT_VALUE=lambda x: (x['X_SORT']))
```

But I'm getting the value of the X_SORT column:

```
  COL1 COL2 X_SORT X_SORT_VALUE
0    X    A   COL1         COL1
1    Y    B   COL2         COL2
2    Z    C   COL1         COL1
```

Rather than getting the value of that column index, like I want:

```
  COL1 COL2 X_SORT X_SORT_VALUE
0    X    A   COL1         X
1    Y    B   COL2         B
2    Z    C   COL1         Z
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [`df.lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) here:

```
df['X_SORT_VALUE'] = df.lookup(df.index,df['X_SORT'])
```

---

```
  COL1 COL2 X_SORT X_SORT_VALUE
0    X    A   COL1            X
1    Y    B   COL2            B
2    Z    C   COL1            Z
```